# meaning of code snippet involving enum class and macro expansion

Tags: c++, enum-class

I encounter the following code in C++. I am new to the language and am not familiar with the syntax.

I understand the basic of macro expansion and enum class. 
I learn that the macro `etokenize` with argument `x1,x2,...,xn` will be replaced by `#x1,#x2,...#xn`. The function `s_tolower` change every charater in a `std::string` to lower case.

```
#define DECL_ENUM_FUNCS(e)        inline const char* enum2str(e e1){ return e##__str__[static_cast<int>(e1)]; } \
                                inline bool str2enum(const std::string& s,e& e1){for(int i=0;i<static_cast<int>(e::End);i++){ if( s==e##__str__[i] ){e1=static_cast<e>(i);return true;} } e1=e::End; return false; } \
                                inline bool str2enumI(const std::string& s,e& e1){for(int i=0;i<static_cast<int>(e::End);i++){ if( s_tolower(s)==s_tolower(e##__str__[i]) ){e1=static_cast<e>(i);return true;} } e1=e::End; return false; } \
                                inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, e const & in_) { o << e##__str__[static_cast<int>(in_)]; return o; }

#define DECL_ENUM(e,x1,...) enum class e : int { x1=0, __VA_ARGS__, End }; const char e##__str__[][256] = {#x1, etokenize(__VA_ARGS__), "Invalid"}; DECL_ENUM_FUNCS(e)
```

My question is on the general syntax, not the detail of functions involved. For instance, Why are there 4 inline functions in the replacement list? 
And what is the last line doing? I apologize if my question is poorly written since I am still a beginner.

I am guessing that

```
DECL_ENUM(type, a,b,c)
```

will be the same as

```
enum class type { a, b, c};
```

Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for the `enum class` part, you miss 2 things:

- The type is set to `int`.
- And `End` value is added to the end.

Then it define utility functions that:

- Convert an enum value to its string representation: `type::a` --> `'a'`
- Find the enum value that correspond to a string: `'a'` --> `type::a`
- Idem by ignoring case: `'A'` --> `type::a`
- Print the text representation to a `std::ostream`: `std::cout << type::a`

Comment: It only specifies the backing store for the enum, it doesn't change its type.  `int` is the default, so a bit enthusiastic.  A "last" enum member is very common, helps to implement value checking.

Comment: By the way, ‘ e__str__[i] ‘ looks to be a none-standard compiler-specific extension. Out of curiosity, what is your tool-chain?

Comment: `e__str__` is a multi dimensional array as `int a[][2] = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};` would be. Nothing compiler specific.